# Eye-Tracker - number of fixation metrics: how to handle zero values when performing statistical tests?

Tags: anova, missing-data, marketing, neuroscience

I collected data on fixation count metrics (also called number of fixations) via eye-tracker technology on a sample of 120 participants. The fixation count was calculated on certain AOIs (areas of interest) in a video: some AOIs are larger (e.g. the logo), other AOIs are smaller (e.g. a company's website).
However, I encountered a problem: in the smaller AOIs, many subjects recorded 'zero' fixations. The reason why this happened is due to two distinct causes:

1. some subjects never looked at the AOI (therefore they could not produce fixations);
2. other subjects looked at the AOI but not for the time needed to produce a fixation (usually this duration is about 100 ms; so they looked at less than 100ms).

My question is the following: if I have to do a statistical analysis (e.g. ANOVA) on the number of fixations, should I convert the subjects with zero values into missing values (i.e. delete the zero and leave the cell empty) or should I perform the statistical test while keeping the zero values? To put it another way: should the zero values (due to the absence of fixations) be kept in the matrix with which the analysis is carried out, or is it better to delete them and perform the statistical test only on the subjects with values equal to and greater than 1?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day

Comment: Use a zero-inflated model.

Comment: What is a 'fixation'? Please explain any necessary jargon.

Comment: For sure, an ocular fixation is a period in which our eyes are locked toward a specific object. Typically, the fixation duration is about 100 milliseconds (for example, if you look at a stimulus for 200ms it is 2 fixations. Conversely, if a stimulus is viewed for less than 100ms, fixation is 0). Thank you User118582 for your advice, this is the first time I have heard of 'zero-inflated model', so I will learn to use this approach instead of a one-way ANOVA.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on @usεr11852's comment:

Don't do ANOVA at all. When the DV is a count, you should usually use a count model. The simplest is Poisson regression, but the assumptions are, in my experience, rarely met, so I usually go to a negative binomial model. If you have an excess of zeroes, there are zero-inflated versions of both the Poisson and NB models.

Another approach is a hurdle model.

There's been discussion of all of these on here and in the literature.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not familiar with Poisson regression and the negative binomial model, so I will look for information on how to perform it. In this regard, I only ask one question: since my independent variable is a qualitative-categorical (3-level) and the dependent variable is quantitative (fixation count), can I use both poisson regression and the negative binomial model on this type of model?

Comment: Yes, Just like with "normal" OLS regression, you can use any kind of independent variable.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I convert the subjects with zero values into missing values (i.e. delete the zero and leave the cell empty)

Aside from the points mentioned in @PeterFlom's answer, it's very, very important that you don't do this. This could very easily change your results in totally unpredictable ways. As a simple example, imagine you have the following data:

- AOI #1 fixation counts: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 11, 10]`

  - Mean = 3
  - Mean excluding zeros = 10
- AOI #2 fixation counts: `[4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]`

  - Mean = 5